# WifiManager.startScan() is deprecated in Android P

Tags: android, wifi

[WifiManager.startScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan()) is deprecated in Android P, how can we initiate a scan for available WiFi networks now?